# Scribus - Masterpage layout on top of content

Tags: page-layout, layout, scribus

I have noticed that whenever I apply a masterpage to a regular page, it always goes to the background, leaving the the content of the regular page on top of it. I'd like to know if it is possible to do the opposite thing.

I have set up a layout where my masterpage is a frame, and it should go on top of the other page content, but I'm unable to find an option to do so.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the next version 1.6, you will be able to put layers from the master pages on top of the ones in the real pages.

It's already in the development version 1.5.x.

For specific cases, there are workarounds to get "common elements" on top of the content of the page.
I would have to know your specific task, to tell if any of them (I know of) can be useful for you.

Comment: I'm currently using the 1.5.1 version, but I haven't found how to do it. Where should I look?

Comment: ciao sekhemty, as written above: in 1.5.x, you can freely use the layers to do so: create two layers a on top of b; in the master page put the top content in the layer a; in the page put the lower content in the layer b. very simple, but, yeah, it's not obvious, either :-)

Comment: btw, i hesitate to put the instructions in the answer, since it's not possible yet to do so in the stable version...